# Is there a way in ggplot to create unequal breaks so that the distance between observation is not homogenous?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering how the y axis of a ggplot can be altered in a way that the distance between factors increases or deacreases hetergenous.

```
x<-c(1:5)
y<-c("Randall","Donavan","Molly","Timothy","Barbara")


plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
plot
```

How can one produce a plot with for example "Randall" and "Donavan" close together and "Timothy" and "Barbara" close togehter but a with a big gab between them.

I do not just want to move the labels but alter the differences between the factors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ggplot2, how to increase tick spacing for similar categories and reduce the spacing for dissimilar categories on the same axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60545652/in-ggplot2-how-to-increase-tick-spacing-for-similar-categories-and-reduce-the-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set different values to the `breaks` of different `labels` in your `scale_y_continuous` command in `ggplot`. You can use the following code as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
x = c(1:5),
y = c("Randall","Donavan","Molly","Timothy","Barbara"),
dist = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 9))


plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = dist)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = df$dist, labels = df$y)
plot
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the labels are on a different scale. Donavan and Randall close, Barbara and Timothy close and big gap between each others.